# python why does my append function not work?

Tags: python, list, append

below are my codes

```
ls = np.repeat(4,5).tolist()
ls.append(100*3)
```

the output I get is as expected

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 300]
```

However when I do this

```
ls = np.repeat(4,5).tolist().append(100*3)
```

my "ls" is blank?? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `append` returns `None`, not the updated list. The list is modified in-place. Notice you didn't have to save the return value of `ls.append` in the first example; `ls` itself reflected the change.

Comment: ah yes I get it now! Now, is there a way to show "np.repeat(4,5).tolist().append(100*3)" in one line so that I get output ls = [4,4,4,4,400] ?

Comment: Yes, there is but you should not write it like that. Writing it in 2 different lines will give you cleaner code.

Comment: yeh agreed, just wanted to see if I could keep it in one line. as its part of a much larger code.

Comment: `(ls := np.repeat(4,5).tolist()).append(100*3)` is the one-liner but as mentioned, treat it as more of a brain-teaser than actual piece of code you should use.

Comment: no that didnt work (ls:= np.repeat(4,5).tolist()).append(100*3)
  File "<ipython-input-162-0ae7b7b0a21f>", line 1
    (ls:= np.repeat(4,5).tolist()).append(100*3)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Update your Python and it will work. (3.8+ specifically)

Comment: ok, i might I might just break it into two codes. thanks for the code though - good to know something like that exists!

Comment: You can also do `ls = np.append(np.repeat(4,5), 100*3).tolist()` for a one-line solution using `np.append`, but as others have suggested fewer lines do not necessarily mean better code.

Comment: great! thanks that was helpful as well.